# How to get "Web Order Number" and "Invoice Number"?

Tags: ios, payment

I'll try to explain you my situation and why I need this numbers

One month ago I renewed the iOS program, I didn't received any mail and any message from Apple and in member center I have this message:

> Your Program purchase is pending and may take up to 24 hours to process. Once processed, you will receive an email from Apple Developer Support. If you have not already purchased your Program, you may do so now.

I sent a message 2 weeks ago to Apple to get more informations about this and I received an answer yesterday and they told me:

> In order to further assist you with your activation code, please reply to this email with the following information of your purchase: 
>   - Web Order Number
>   - Invoice Number

So How could I get this numbers if the payment is not done??

Thanks,

Sorry if my english is not perfect, and if you want more informations tell me

Comment: This seems like a question better posed to Apple, not SO.

Comment: 2 weeks for this, I think it's too much, this is why I posed it here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that information if you go to the store.apple.com (or the equivalent for another country) then to Account > Order Status.

Comment: Thanks, I have no numbers and this message: Cancelled  on October 22, 2013

And I did the renew on October 14, so??